# How to do a grails while loop a certain number of times

Tags: grails

How can I kick a while loop only n times in grails/groovy in side the gsp?
This is my current approach:

```
%{-- <%= "It's groovy, man".take(88)    %> --}%

    <g:set var="i" value="${messages.size()}"/>
    <g:set var="x" value="<%= i - 3 %>/>"
    <g:while test="${i > x}">
    <g:set var="i" value="${i-1}"/>
      ... fancy html here
      <%= messages[i].name %>
    </g:while>
```

**Solution:**

```
  <g:set var="i" value="${messages.size()}"/>
    <g:set var="k" value="${i-3}"/>
    <g:while test="${i > k}">
```

Comment: i thought groovy can do calculation inside the script definition and just substracted my desired amount of looping times from the overall length of my collection

Comment: this works:<g:set var="k" value="${i-3}"/>
<g:while test="${i > k}">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I would do. This is assuming you want to get the last X items in a list, which is what I THINK you are asking, although it isn't very clear. This is also assuming messages is a list.

```
<g:set var="length" value="${messages.size()}" />
<g:each in="${messages.getAt((Math.min(length,3)*-1)..-1)}" var="message">
... fancy html here
      <%= message.name %>
</g:each>
```

Here were the tests I did to confirm this:

```
def list = [1,2]
def x = list.size()
assert [1,2] == list.getAt((Math.min(x,3)*-1)..-1)
list = [1,2,3]
x = list.size()
assert [1,2,3] == list.getAt((Math.min(x,3)*-1)..-1)
list = [1,2,3,4]
x = list.size()
assert [2,3,4] == list.getAt((Math.min(x,3)*-1)..-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
<g:each var="foo" in="${ ((i-k)..k) }">
    ...
</g:each>
```